# Как передать переменную из одной функции в другую?

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    name_zip_pass = str(callback_query.from_user.id) + "_" + str(random.randint(10000, 99999))

async def process_callback_button5(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_document(callback_query.from_user.id, open(f'zip/{name_mane}.zip', 'rb'))
```

Мне нужно передать значение переменной name_zip_pass из process_callback_button1 в process_callback_button5

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы передать значение переменной `name_zip_pass` из одной функции в другую, надо, для начала, объявить эту переменную глобальной

Чтобы объявить переменную `name_zip_pass` глобальной, надо до функции написать её объявление, например, `name_zip_pass = ""`

Или внутри функции указать, что переменная глобальная `global name_zip_pass`

Comment: global name_zip_pass
name_zip_pass = str(call_q.from_user.id) + "_" + str(random.randint(10000, 99999)) я вынес за функцию но теперь ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Ничего не выноси за функцию, добавь только внутри первой функции  ```global name_zip_pass``` и всё

Comment: name_zip_pass = str(callback_query.from_user.id) + "_" + str(random.randint(10000, 99999))
    global name_zip_pass где global name_zip_pass красным подчеркиваетя

Comment: @SlimThugs как же ты так вынес за функцию то, что не может жить за функцией ? ```callback_query``` может жить только внутри функции, это же параметр функции, это то же самое, как чай вынести за пределы кружки

Comment: я вернул ее обратно

Comment: почитай как используется глобал в функциях и сделай новый проект, для того, чтобы разобраться с областью видимости переменных. Сделай сам новые функции, а эти пока оставь

Comment: чтобы ты мог объявить переменную глобальной, кажется, её надо инициализировать вне функции ( но это не точно ). Попробуй сам сделать несколько переменных и поиграйся